# What are the benefits of built_value enums over normal enums from the language

Tags: enums, dart, flutter

In the [built_value](https://github.com/google/built_value.dart) lib I found the [example how to make enums](https://github.com/google/built_value.dart/blob/master/example/lib/enums.dart). So I'm a bit confused. Because I do not see right away what are the benefits of useing the built_value enums. Does some one know it? What do I overlook?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Mostly that they can easily be de/serialized from/to JSON.

Darts built-in enums are quite a bad fit where serialization is needed.

Answer (score 12):

Serialization is one thing; the other major one is that they are proper classes: you can add code to them, and they can implement interfaces.

In this way they're much like Java's enums.